# How to add " to a string in python

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to start a torrent downloader in windows, which is executed from the command prompt. It takes in a command such as `torrent "magnet_link"`. The problem I'm having is when I start the command from python using `os.system("start /wait cmd /c torrent " + '"' + link + '"')` for some reason the ***"*** character is not shown in the command prompt window launched, making the command useless. The response I am getting is: `'dn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: can you attach a scree shot?

Comment: Can you show what you are getting?

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use can use built-in `str.center`:

```
link = 'http://stackoverflow.com'
print("start /wait cmd /c torrent %s" % link.center(len(link)+2, '"'))

# start /wait cmd /c torrent "http://stackoverflow.com"
```

Comment: Doesn't this generate the same string as the code Daquaney wrote?

Answer (score 2):

Quotation marks in shell are interpreted if you do not escape them. To escape them, prepend a backslash. Look here:

```
os.system("start /wait cmd /c torrent \\\"{}\\\"".format(link))
```

What happens:

- `\\` is interpreted as a single backslash
- `\"` is interpreted as a quotation mark
- `.format(link)` replaces `{}` with `link`, to avoid adding strings (just for the style of code)

Comment: when I put this in my code it says that the {} is an invalid syntax

Comment: Then you are probably using Python 2 and not 3, the formatting syntax there is a bit more complicated, as it can be seen in Chris answer.